# if entry has same url segment

Tags: url

I have a Structure that has the URL setup like this..

Top-Level Entries - {slug}
Nested Entries - {parent.uri}/{slug}

How do I list all entries that have the same segment1 of their URL as to what is on the current page the user is on.

i.e if I am on page  http://example.com/vacation

I want to list all structure entries that have 'vacation' as the first segment of the URL.

i.e

/vacation/snow
/vacation/coastal

but it would not show any entries from the structure that are like this:

/advice/what-to-bring
/advice/weather-warnings
/contact

So basically I want to do this...

if segment1 = entry url segment1 display entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have an `entry` in the same `structure`, the simplest method is probably to use the `parent` and `descendants` properties of the [EntryModel](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/EntryModel).

```
{% set entries = entry.parent.descendants %}
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

A more round about way would be to get the segment through `craft.request.segment`, use that to get the entry, and use `descendants` to get the children.

```
{% set segment = craft.request.segment(1) %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('myStructureHandle').slug(segment).first.descendants %}
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Or, if you only want the `siblings` without the current entry, you could use:

```
{% set entries = entry.siblings %}
```